# Is it dangerous to use an ungrounded USB C charger to charge a laptop?

Tags: power-supply, grounding

I have a laptop (with an aluminium case) that charges via USB C. The original power brick is 95W (but uses 60W charging in standard mode if I don't enable fast charging in software) and it has a standard [CEE 7/7 plug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets#/media/File:CEE_7-7.jpg).

When I travel or am in another room, I use a small unofficial multiple-output charging brick, rated 60W on the usb C output, which doesn't have grounding, only the standard 2 pin plug ([CEE 7/16 Europlug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug)).

[After a few weeks] I noticed that I get very small electric shocks when touching the corners of the laptop case with the forearms and also the touchpad had weird responses and ghost touches when using it but only very rarely. Today I realised this only happens when using the other, non grounded charger so I pulled out the digital multimeter and I get around 20V AC between the laptop case and my hand (with small jumps to 40V). DC reads are almost zero, probably within reading error (~0.4V). This doesn't happen with the original charger so my guess is that it's related to the lack of grounding, is this correct?

My main question is: is this dangerous for the device? Should I stop using the secondary charger completely? Should I only use it when not touching the laptop? Or is this normal for a low power device and grounding is not needed/mandatory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not likely to be dangerous to humans, but to devices if connected together.

Yes, it happens because it is designed to be connected to ungrounded socket, and for electromagnetic compatibility reasons it contains common-mode capacitor between unisolated mains side and isolated low voltage output side which weakly couples mains to laptop.

And yes, this is quite normal for power supplies which use ungrounded inlet. Especially no-name cheap ones can be so terrible you can't touch a device with metal case.

It should not be dangerous, and as long the laptop is only connected to charger there is no problems. But there is a chance that while the charger is connected, connecting it to another device like a grounded monitor there can be high potential difference when the connectors touch, and the capacitor discharge current can be so high you see small sparks. The connector must be good quality and hot pluggable so the voltage difference or discharge current does not go via data pins as it can do permanent damage.

Basically, almost all manuals of devices with ungrounded 2-pole plugs instruct to disconnect mains plugs of devices being connected, so I would do the same here so nothing breaks.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.